# PDF viewer plugin, Phonegap

Tags: xcode, pdf, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am looking for a good PDF viewer for phonegap (can even be a for $$), with Thumbnail action and etc.

SO far I use the childbrowser  plugin which is lacking in functionality.

Does someone  know about some pluginx/kits/examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found two options:

- http://pspdfkit.com/  (You have to pay for license)
- https://github.com/vfr/Reader (Free)

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one is not for Phonegap.

An interesting alternative is [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) project, [demo](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html).

Is a Javascript Viewer that works with HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

n Android, you can view the pdfs using Android Intents. This will show you all the pdf viewers available in your phone. You can select any and view the pdf

Eg :

```
private void showPdfAndroid(String url) throws IOException {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(url);

    String extension = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    String type = "";

    if (extension.toLowerCase().equals("pdf")) {
        type = "application/pdf";
        Log.d("application/pdf", "application/pdf");
    } 

    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
    cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);

    Log.d("FileViewerPlugin", "View complete in" + url);


}
```